# Received faxed copy of W2 instead of orginal document?

Tags: united-states, w2

I was let go from my job in December (they are outsourcing and bosses are retiring soon I think). For 7 years while working there I received an original copy of my W2. A week after January 31st, I called in asking about it since I had not heard or received anything and they said to come pick it up.

Upon reviewing the document at home, I realized what I retrieved was a Faxed copy of my W2 (blank on back and with fax number date/time at top - appears his accountant faxed it to his business). This is very concerning for 2 reasons:

1) I never gave consent for my W2 to be sent electronically email or fax to anyone. I understand there are consent laws regarding email. Is the same true for Fax? Isn't this not a secure method? Can't find much info. They don't exactly follow best practices for anything.

2) For future documentation/proof issues, is there anything I need to be concerned about regarding the fact they gave me a faxed copy instead of the original? Will I possibly be screwed over 3 - 7 years down the line for any reason? Finding out they put something incorrect on this copy? I have no idea.

I just don't trust these people at all whatsoever. Have already put a fraud alert and following up with a credit freeze.

Comment: Voting to close as not a workplace issue. [money.se] *may* be a good place for this question though I'm not sure.

Comment: A location tag would be useful for this

Comment: @RobBailey W2 is a United States form, but I've added the tag regardless.

Comment: Faxing is very secure.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if a W-2 is sent to you via mail, email, or fax. The IRS doesn't care.

If you are planning to sue your former employer (because of the fax or something else), consult your lawyer.

Comment: Yeah, I always print my documents from my online accounts when I can, as I never know when they will show up in the mail.